# How to check if a list from DocumentSnaphot is empty?

Tags: flutter

I have a class `IsProduct` where I get data from another class, `Product`. In my class `Product` I have a `List` of `String`, but in my `IsProduct` class I just want to get the first item of the `List` as a `String`. I can get the first item with `doc['images'][0]`, but sometimes my `List` is empty and it returns an error. How can I fix this?

```
class IsProduct {
 IsProduct.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  name = doc['name'] as String;
  //I tried this but it doesn't work
  image = doc['images'][0] == [] ? '' : doc['images'][0] as String;
  pid = doc['pid'] as String;
  description = doc['description'] as String;
  storeId = doc['storeId'] as String;
  i = doc['i'] as int;
}

String name;
String image;
String pid;
String storeId;
String description;
int i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  image = doc['images'].isEmpty ? '' : doc['images'][0] as String;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. In fact it has thrown another error ```Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast```.

Comment: replace `i = doc['i'] as int;` with `i = int.parse(doc['i']);`

Comment: Could you send at which line or variable the error is happening

Comment: ```Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
#0      new IsProduct.fromDocument
#1      IsProductManager.loadAllIsProduct.<anonymous closure>
#2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:417:31)
#3      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:343:26)
#4      new List.from (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:38:29)
#5      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:68:17)
#6      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:211:44)
#7      IsProductManager.loadAllIsProduct```.

Comment: If I have an image it works okay, so I believe the error is on the list itself.